# To setText() while programs processing

Tags: java, swing

From my project, I try to make a dictionary brute-force by a method then output any trying and a correct words to `textField` at the main class.

Output should be

> Trying a...
>   Trying b...
>   Trying c...
>   Found! c is correct.

and this is my code.

```java
public static String MD5Dict(String str, String fpth){
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fpth))){
        String sCurrentLine;
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            Encryption encrypt = new Encryption();
            System.out.println("Trying "+sCurrentLine+"..."); //problem is in this line
            if(str.equals(encrypt.MD5Hashing(sCurrentLine))){
                return sCurrentLine;
            }
        }
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To setText() while programs processing

It sounds like good reason to use background task with UI updates (in your case, TextField updates). I recommend you to read some tutorial about [SwingWorker](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/). [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) or [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) is also official documentation.